# Populating a color array with every 8th pixel in an image. C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, rgb

I have an image that is 512x280 pixels. I want to populate a 64x35 array with every 8th pixel in the matrix.

Here is what I have right now:

```
        Color[,] imgArray = new Color[b.Width, b.Height];
        for (int y = 0; y < 35; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
            {
                imgArray[x, y] = b.GetPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
```

But that will get just the top corner of the image. How would I change the loop so it grabs every 8th pixel to fill the array with?

edit: I think I may have gotten it. Can someone read this and assure me that it is correct?

```
        Color[,] imgArray = new Color[64, 35];
        for (int y = 0; y < 280; y+=8)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 512; x+=8)
            {
                imgArray[x, y] = b.GetPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to divide your x and y counters by 8 when assigning to your target array.

Comment: Like this?  imgArray[x/8, y/8] = b.GetPixel(x, y);

Comment: I recommend you replace your magic numbers either with variables or constants.  `const int width = 64, height = 35, sampleDensity = 8;` ... `for(int y = 0; y < height * sampleDensity; y += sampleDensity)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Simply multiply the coordinates by 8 when you get the pixels:

```
Color[,] imgArray = new Color[64, 35];
for (int y = 0; y < 35; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
    imgArray[x, y] = b.GetPixel(x * 8, y * 8);
  }
}
```